# "to have merchant's ears"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

Is the expression "to have merchant's ears" an idiom or a recognized adage, meaning "pretending not to understand"?

Please explain with examples or provide a better idiomatic phrase.

Comment: Either provide your own citations, or this is not a real question.

Comment: *Could* it be? Yes.  *Is* it? No.  You might say, "Don't waste your breath. It'll *fall on deaf ears.*"  or "He's *feigning ignorance.*"

Comment: I did find [music to merchants' ears](http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=9406EEDB103DE733A25757C2A9639C946091D6CF) in a few instances but nothing that suggests *pretending not to understand*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, already in the sixteenth century the merchant and trades- man
>   had acquired a notorious name for fraudulent business habits. Piers
>   Ploughman assigned his selling powers to "the grace of guile gone
>   among" his wares.3 "To play the Merchant with" was synonymous with
>   cheating, and "**to have Merchant's ears" meant to affect not to hear
>   when the terms of bargains proved disadvantageous**.* -Middlemen in English business, particularly between 1660 and 1760, by Ray Bert Westerfield ... 1915.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but I don't think it's a recognized one. Found some usage in here: [to have a merchant's ears](http://deyimyerindeyse.com/?page_id=136), but it's in a different language.

> *Duymazdan gelmek*. (literally “To have a merchant’s ears”) = to turn a deaf ear, to pretend not to hear.

So, I think the terms ***feigning ignorance*** or ***play dumb*** would be better.

Comment: The etymology is from shipping -I don't have the reference but IIRC, merchants who guaranteed cargo were notorious for seeking information from other faster vessels because of their respondentia.  A loss at sea was ruin and their merchant's ears was a temporary salvation

Comment: You have the answer in the link. Your example is in [Turkish](http://tureng.com/search/duymazdan%20gelmek) but it is the translation of a famous proverb in a different language.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider I was hoping Sudhir would have edited his answer. To have merchants' ears is the translation of the Italian expression: **fare orecchio da mercante** I wish I had picked up on it earlier, it completely passed me by, however it is common in Italy. This is the excerpt from the 15th century play: *Avvertite a non parlare; e se la madre dicesse qualcosa che non vi andasse per la fantasia*, **fate orecchi di mercatante**. *Come orecchi di mercatante? Non odono se non le cose che fanno per loro*. Basically the speaker is encouraging the listener to ignore his mother's words!

Comment: Link to [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_026.html) (it's in italian).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to the English idiom known as:

[turn a deaf ear](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+deaf+ear)(to someone or something):

> to ignore what someone says; to ignore a cry for help. How can you just turn a deaf ear to their cries for food and shelter? Jack turned a deaf ear to our pleading.

[turn a deaf ear](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/turn+a+deaf+ear):

> Refuse to listen, as in You can plead all day but he's turning a deaf ear to everyone . This expression dates from the first half of the 1400s and was in most proverb collections from 1546 on.
>
> Also *fall on deaf ears*

The act of not hearing is deliberate.